# c++: priority_queue of struct and decltype comparator

Tags: c++, lambda, priority-queue, decltype

```
class Solution {

    struct tree{
        int x;
        int y;
        int height;
    }; 



public:
    int cutOffTree(vector<vector<int>>& forest) {

         auto lambda1 =  [](tree &t1, tree &t2){return t1.height < t2.height;};

         priority_queue<tree, vector<tree>, decltype(lambda1)> pq1;

        return 0;
    }
};
```

but got the error:

[image]

Any idea what I did wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Did you cut off the error message? If so, please don't do that.

Comment: Did you try std::priority_queue ... [this code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0u3MxqMxsdrGMCES) compiles and runs just fine.

Comment: If you run a Google search for whatever actual error message you are getting from the compiler, you should get plenty of hints that explain exactly what's wrong with the parameters to your lambda comparator. There should be a crapton of dupes here, for this common error, but it's not obvious which keywords will find them...

Comment: @BlueTune It only compiles fine because you use the `-std=c++2a` flag for experimental C++20 support, see my answer below. `std::` is not the problem here, because most likely OP is using `using namespace std;` (for better or worse and they should have provided a complete code example in any case).

Comment: @Edamame You should know that images of text are not acceptable...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`priority_queue` requires an instance of the `Compare` type which is used for comparison.

The default constructor of `priority_queue` tries to construct the instance as `Compare()`. Since `Compare` here is a closure type it will fail, because closure types are not default-constructible.

You need to provide the instance to the constructor. It will save a copy of it for later use:

```
priority_queue<tree, vector<tree>, decltype(lambda1)> pq1{lambda1};
```

---

As it stands currently, this will not be necessary anymore in C++20 for lambdas without capture such as here, because they will be made default-constructible. You may try this out with the experimental C++20 support in compilers with e.g. the `-std=c++2a` or `/std:c++latest` flags to your compiler.

---

Since C++17 you can also use class template argument deduction to avoid naming the lambda and the value type twice:

```
priority_queue pq1{lambda1, vector<tree>};
```